# Check if any radio input is checked

Tags: javascript, html

```js
if (document.querySelector("input[name='maca']")).getAttribute("checked")
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="maca" id="maca1">
<input type="radio" name="maca" id="maca2">
```

I want to check if any one of the input type radio buttons with the same name is checked.

Comment: Yes but how to check if any is selected? By default they are both deselected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select every radio button with that name with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), then use [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check whether one of the items in the list is checked:

```js
const radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="maca"]')
const oneChecked = [...radioButtons].some(e => e.checked)
console.log(oneChecked)
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="maca" id="maca1">
<input type="radio" name="maca" id="maca2" checked>
```

Alternatively, you can try selecting the checked radio button (with the [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) pseudo-class) and see if an element was selected:

```js
if(document.querySelector('input[name="maca"]:checked')){
  console.log('checked')
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="maca" id="maca1">
<input type="radio" name="maca" id="maca2" checked>
```

Comment: It is working! Thanks a lot!